# Make `previous_post_link()` Function Show The Post After Next i.e. Jump A Post

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, previous-post-link

Is it possible when using the `previous_post_link()` function to make it get the previous post after next i.e. make it skip a post. So if you're on post 5 in numerical order it skips to post 3?

The reason being I have custom post type `single-cpt.php` file that pulls in two posts, so when using the previous post link out of the box it means when you go to the next post, one of the ones from the previous post is there again.

Any help would be fabulous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$current_id = get_the_ID();
$cpt = get_post_type();
$all_ids = get_posts(array(
    'fields'          => 'ids',
    'posts_per_page'  => -1,
    'post_type' => $cpt,
    'order_by' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
));
$prev_key = array_search($current_id, $all_ids) - 2;
$next_key = array_search($current_id, $all_ids) + 2;
if(array_key_exists($prev_key, $all_ids)){
    $prev_link = get_the_permalink($all_ids[$prev_key]);
    echo $prev_link;
}
if(array_key_exists($next_key, $all_ids)){
    $next_link = get_the_permalink($all_ids[$next_key]);
    echo $next_link;
}
```

So I queried all the posts IDs from the current post type. Then since it’s a simple array key=>value, just found the current post key in the array and just added or subtracted so if your current post is the 8th one, your next is 10 and you previous is 6. Then if your array doesn’t have enough keys, say your current was the 8th but your array only had 9 that will mess it up, I check to see if the key exists. If it does, use get_the_permalink() with the value of the desired key.

Probably not the most graceful way to do it but…

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a couple functions that trick WordPress into thinking we're on the previous/next post before calling `previous_post_link` or `next_post_link`:

```
/**
 * Displays the next post link that is adjacent to the next post.
 *
 * @param object       $next_post      Optional. The next post to reference. Default is current post.
 * @param string       $format         Optional. Link anchor format. Default '&laquo; %link'.
 * @param string       $link           Optional. Link permalink format. Default '%title'
 * @param bool         $in_same_term   Optional. Whether link should be in a same taxonomy term. Default false.
 * @param array|string $excluded_terms Optional. Array or comma-separated list of excluded term IDs. Default empty.
 * @param string       $taxonomy       Optional. Taxonomy, if $in_same_term is true. Default 'category'.
 */
function next_next_post_link( $next_post = null, $format = '%link &raquo;', $link = '%title', $in_same_term = false, $excluded_terms = '', $taxonomy = 'category' ) {
    global $post;

    // Keep track of the current post so we can reset back later.
    $current_post = $post;

    // If a "next post" is specified, use that.
    if ( $next_post ) {
        $post = $next_post;
        setup_postdata( $post );
    }

    // Make WordPress think we're on the next post.
    $post = get_next_post();
    setup_postdata( $post );

    // Echo the next post link, skipping the next post.
    next_post_link( $format, $link, $in_same_term, $excluded_terms, $taxonomy );

    // Reset everything back.
    $post = $current_post;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}


/**
 * Displays the previous post link that is adjacent to the previous post.
 *
 * @param object       $previous_post  Optional. The previous post to reference. Default is current post.
 * @param string       $format         Optional. Link anchor format. Default '&laquo; %link'.
 * @param string       $link           Optional. Link permalink format. Default '%title'.
 * @param bool         $in_same_term   Optional. Whether link should be in a same taxonomy term. Default false.
 * @param array|string $excluded_terms Optional. Array or comma-separated list of excluded term IDs. Default empty.
 * @param string       $taxonomy       Optional. Taxonomy, if $in_same_term is true. Default 'category'.
 */
function previous_previous_post_link( $previous_post = null, $format = '%link &raquo;', $link = '%title', $in_same_term = false, $excluded_terms = '', $taxonomy = 'category' ) {
    global $post;

    // Keep track of the current post so we can reset back later.
    $current_post = $post;

    // If a "previous post" is specified, use that.
    if ( $previous_post ) {
        $post = $previous_post;
        setup_postdata( $post );
    }

    // Make WordPress think we're on the previous post.
    $post = get_previous_post();
    setup_postdata( $post );

    // Echo the previous post link, skipping the previous post.
    previous_post_link( $format, $link, $in_same_term, $excluded_terms, $taxonomy );

    // Reset everything back.
    $post = $current_post;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Add those functions to your `functions.php` file, and use `next_next_post_link` and `previous_previous_post_link` the same way you would use `next_post_link` and `previous_post_link`

Result:
[image: screenshot showing post #3 with links to post #1 and post #5]

Comment: Hi @NateAllen this didn't work it still just goes to the next post ? I'm wondering of it's because of the code I'm also using on this post (from the answer marked as correct) https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/372578/pull-two-posts-into-custom-post-type-single-cpt-php

Comment: @TheChewy I updated the code so you can pass in the next post to reference. So you would do `previous_previous_post_link($next_post)`. That should work with the code you referenced. I just tested and it worked for me.

Comment: that still doesn't work. Although I am a bit confused about the line you added in the comment in terms of where that goes? Also just to let you know I'm only going to be using it on previous posts not next posts. I do really appreciate you trying to help by the way.